# Creating a boolean array by prime number

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to create an N-by-N Boolean array `a[][]` in such a way that `a[i][j]` is true if `i` and `j` are relatively prime, and false otherwise.

My code is

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int N = 12;
    boolean[][] a = new boolean[N][N];

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++){
            if(i%j == 0){
                a[i][j] = false;
            }else{
                a[i][j] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    printArray(a);
}


public static void printArray(boolean[][] a){
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j< a[i].length; j++){
            System.out.printf(a[i][j]);
            System.out.printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

The running exception is Exception in thread "main"

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
        at Array.main(Array.java:8)
```

How could I fix my code?

Comment: What results you ware expecting for `0%0`? Or for others `x%0`?

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++){
            if(i%j == 0)
```

When `i` is 0, and/or `j` is 0, you're dividing by 0 (`i%j`).
You can't do that.

Try to think around this. Maybe run `i` and `j` from 1 instead of 0, and then correct for it?

Comment: yes. it works. One more question, how could I print the Boolean array? I try to use printf function but its failed.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)
        std::cout << a[i][j] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;` }